# Xcode, C++ (not iOS) How can I fix dyld: Library not loaded runtime error

Tags: c++, xcode, libraries, dylib

I'm pretty new to development using Xcode and a Mac. I'm trying to link a .dylib, so I can use it in my application. However, when the application compiles, I immediately get this runtime error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libraryname.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/jon/Documents/myApplication/Debug/myApplication.app/Contents/MacOS/myApplication
Reason: image not found
```

I've tried adding

```
@executable_path/../Frameworks
```

into Runpath search paths, and adding the directory in the Library Search Paths in build settings, which seemed to be other answers to similar problems on this site, unfortunately, not this one though.

I've read something about using

```
install_name_tool -change /Users/jon/Documents/myApplication/lib/libraryName/lib/libraryName.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks libraryName.dylib
```

on the library I'm trying to use, however, this does not seem to get rid of the runtime error either.

I feel like this should be a fairly easy error to fix, but I just don't seem to be able to get my head around it. Is anyone able to help me out?

Thank you